Define different ILM policyes for each elasticAgent integration
I have an ELK cluster with a fleetServer and some elasticAgents.
As for now, I've added 2 prometheus integration to scrape the metrics from 2 different applications:

The namespace of both prometheus package_polices is: XXX
The data_stream.dataset for the prometheus package_policy that scrapes the metrics for the application A is "prometheus.collector.appa"
The data_stream.dataset for the prometheus package_policy that scrapes the metrics for the application B is "prometheus.collector.appb"

I can see the metrics in the following data streams:

metrics-prometheus.collector.appa
metrics-prometheus.collector.appb

The question is: I need to have a different ILM policy for appa and appb (the default metrics policy is not good for us). How can I define those ilm policies and assign it to the 2 different datastreams?
I tried this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/example-using-index-lifecycle-policy.html but it dind't help (unless I did something wrong)
Thank you

Right, the way this works is a bit "over the top/complex" but you can do this.
Elastic Agent integrations create an index for their own integration(s), to achieve what you are looking for, you need to look into the index component templates and find the one named <integrationname>_custom. In there you can specify the custom ILM using the normal index settings syntax in the settings tab.
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "<your_ilm_policy_name>
    }
  }
}

The same applies to any integration btw.
